# Binary Insert Method - handling edge cases

Tags: python, optimization, algorithm, binary-search

I've created a function that uses binary search to insert an element into an array (similar to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/binary-search-for-inserting-in-array)).  I haven't benchmarked it, but based on my knowledge it should get \$O(1)\$ in the best case (i.e., appending an item to the end of the list) and \$O(nlogn)\$ in the average/worst case (I have no numbers to back this up - frankly I don't have much experience with benchmarking, so have mercy on me.)

Here's the binary search algorithm:

```
def binary_search(a, x):
    mid = 0
    min = 0
    max = len(a)

    # Deal with the edge cases
    if x < a[min]:
        return -1
    if x > a[max-1]:
        return max

    # Now that we know that the value is in range,
    # perform the actual search
    while min < max:
        mid = mid_point(min,max)
        if x < a[mid]:
            max = mid - 1
        elif x > a[mid]:
            min = mid + 1
        else:
            return mid

    # Another edge case
    return min if a[min] >= x else min + 1
```

This will return the index to insert the element into. The function used to perform the insertion is simple:

```
def binary_insert(array, value):
    index = binary_search(array,value)
    if index < 0: # Just append the value to the end of the list
        array.insert(0,value)
    else:
        array.insert(index,value)
```

The function works on a pre-sorted list (a requirement of a binary search) and maintains the list in sorted order. For example inserting `[0..10)` (aka `[0,1,2,...,8,9]`) into `[-1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` yields `[-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10]`

You may have noticed that the return statement (the last one) for `binary_search` is very messy, and not very intuitive.  Would like to be able to incorporate that logic into the `while` loop somehow, or at least simplify it.  Does anyone have an idea of how I could do this? (Side question: how do I benchmark this?)

EDIT:

This is the `mid_point` function.

```
def mid_point(x, y):
    return (x+y)/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go deep into the implementation of binary search and insertion, my advice is to take a look at the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/bisect.html) in the standard library:

```
def insort_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Insert item x in list a, and keep it sorted assuming a is sorted.

    If x is already in a, insert it to the left of the leftmost x.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    a.insert(lo, x)


def bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e < x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e >= x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just before the leftmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo
```

Comment: Is this the code used by the module? (I never knew about the `//` operator, that's cool)

Comment: @sotrh Yes, that's the code in python 2.7.6 stdlib. Note that `//` is floor division whose behavior is consistent in python 2 and 3, but regular `/` doesn't behave the same way. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/183870/183066).

Comment: So basically `insort_left` and `bisect_left` do the same thing except `insort_left` inserts `x` into the list while `bisect_left` just returns where it should be inserted?

Comment: @sotrh Correct. As pointed out by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left) `bisect.insort_left` is equivalent to `a.insert(bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo, hi), x)`

Comment: It's good to know about this module. I wrote my code as a mock which I'll use to write the java equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts:

For benchmarking there are two modules folks usually use:

cProfile

[bettertimeit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bettertimeit/1.1.2)

I put an example in a previous post located here:

[Profiling](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56263/better-sorting-speed/56631#56631)

Also, can you please post the entire script? Just want to make sure I have full context. Namely mid_point.

Comment: I updated the post to include `mid_point`

Comment: I didn't know about `bettertimeit`, thanks.

Comment: I tried the `bettertimeit` module using the code from your [other answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56263/better-sorting-speed/56631#56631), but I'm getting `ImportError: No module named bettertimeit` when I try to run it.

Comment: I'm running python 2.7.6 by the way.

Comment: @sotrh `bettertimeit` is not part of the stdlib. Your probably need to install it.

Comment: how might I do that?

Comment: pip insstall bettertimeit

Comment: or .. use easy_install pip, then run pip..  :-)